# git go back to a previous commit before reset hard

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I changed some code, then ran

```
git add .
git commit -m "message1"
```

But after that, I did

```
git reset hard
git pull
git push
```

(The push actually did nothing, of course.)

Now I want to retrieve the state of my files at the point of commit "message1". How can I do that?

Comment: You may get lucky with [`git reflog`](http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits). In general, `git reset hard` is one of those "don't do it unless you really really mean it" things. 99% of the time you should just move the commit you don't want to its own branch in case you decide you do want it later.

Comment: git reflog does give me that commit that I need like this "3ee1815 HEAD@{5}: commit: Committing vmmap and fork classes". What should I do to move the head to this commit? I have tried git reset --hard <3ee1815> but it gives an error

Comment: @chris-hayes when you say "move the commit" what approach would you be using here to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: @KhawarAli I'm not sure, unfortunately; I've never used `git reflog` myself, I'm just familiar with its existence.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark You have a few options. If the commit is on `master` (for example), you can create a new branch from that point and then use `git reset hard` on `master`. Or you can create the new branch from an older point, and use `git cherry-pick` to grab the commit you want to save. There's probably a bunch of other ways as well.

Comment: `git reset hard` is not a valid command unless you have some kind of branch (or other treeish) called `hard` which, I think, is unlikely. I'm presuming that you meant `git reset --hard`. If you simply say `git reset --hard`, it will reset to your current position (i.e. effectively do nothing) so your commit will not be lost. Doing a `git log` should make that obvious. In summary, you already are at commit "message 1" and don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reset hard` resets the *index* (not the working directory) to the state of the branch called `hard`. So nothing actually changed: you can do a simple `git reset` to just reset the index. Nothing else has changed anyway.

If you did a `git reset --hard` then that’s a different thing. This will reset the index and uncommitted changes in the working directory to the state of HEAD, i.e. the last commit of your current branch. Since you made a commit directly before that command, you also lose nothing in case you included all changes of your working directory in that commit. If you did not, then you’re out of luck, and those uncommitted changes that never even made it to the index are lost.

The `git pull` will fetch from the remote and merge any changes into your branch, so this is where something might have actually changed. Since you did a commit locally, there are two cases: You were up to date and nothing was changed; there were changes on the remote and Git created a merge commit. In the latter case, you can revert that using `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`. You can also check the reflog using `git reflog` to see where HEAD was pointing to previously.

As for the `git push`, it’s not obvious that it doesn’t do anything. Actually, since you made a commit locally, it should have done something. It should have pushed your commit and an eventual merge commit (as per above) to the remote. In that case, it’s not recommended to go back again (with above command) to undo those changes, since you should never remove commits you have already published.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `git reflog`. It will display the full history of what you did in your repository.
Once you track the commit that you want to revert to check it out, open a new branch (since you will be in detached HEAD) and continue your work from that point.

### Second Thing

Once you adding content to the stash (index) you can always recover it as long as your gc did not run. you can use `git fsck` to find out the SHA-1 of those dangaling files and recover them using `git cat-file -p' to view the content and copy it to your needs.